# Symfony2 & sonata-admin: кастомные шаблоны в edit-форме

Tags: php, symfony2

Всем доброго времени суток.
Весь день пытаюсь решить задачу (symfony2 и sonata-admin).
Есть массив булевых данных, который надо вывести как матрицу чекбоксов.

В соответствующем классе есть настройка формы

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('matrix','collection',array(
            'data'=>  $this->subject->getArrayOfBoolean(),
            'type'=>'checkbox',
            'required'=>false,
        ));
}
```

С вводом-выводом данных как коллекции чекбоксов проблем нет.  
Но навесить свой шаблон никак не получается.  
В гугле решение пока не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому интересно: решил задачу через [регистрацию типов в symfomy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл 2 варианта, правда под админку для монги
Вариант 1: можно просто добавить опцию template в массив опций из 3-го параметра.

```
->add('pictures', 'array', array('template' => 'NewsBundle:News:_admin_show_news_pictures.html.twig'))
```

Вариант 2: для какого-то типа прописать свой шаблон в конфиге, вот пример для монги:

```
sonata_doctrine_mongo_db_admin:
    templates:
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
            show:
                array:      BrotherCMSBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                news_tags:  SolNewsBundle:News:admin_show_news_tags.html.twig
```

Можно конечно и тип полностью зарегистрировать, но мне как правило хватало подстановки шаблона.